# Which Version of Exchange Server 2013 should i use

Tags: exchange-server, windows-server, versions

I'm setting up an Exchange Server for private use.
On this Exchange Server there will be up to 10 Users.

Now i don't know which version of Exchange 2013 i have to use.
I saw that the Exchange 2013 Standard has 5 mailbox databases and the Enterprise Version 100 mailbox databases.

But what is a Mailbox Database? Does it need 1 mailbox database per user?

If it's so: i need the Exchange Server 2013 Enterprise for 10 users, right?

Sorry if the question is a little bit stupid, but i just want to be sure.

Thank you for your answer and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a mailbox database per user. You can configure all 10 user mailboxes within one mailbox database.

you only need more than 5 mailbox databases if you are using a really big setup with distributed servers and/or database availability groups for high availability.

So, according to your requirements Exchange 2013 Standard Edition should be fine.